# Display long Int from access to a text box

Tags: c#, telerik, oledbdatareader

I want to fill the text box with the ID of the customer name that has been selected in a combo box. I am getting error under customerID saying

---

> Unknown method 'GetInt32(string)'of 'System.Data.Oledb.OledbDataReader'

---

this is the copy of the whole code

```
        private void RadMultiColumnComboBox1SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= RoadRunnerDB.mdb";
        string query = "select * from RoadRunnerDB.customerList where customerCompanyName = '" + radMultiColumnComboBox1 + "';";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);            
        OleDbDataReader rd;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rd.Read())
            {                             //Error is under here
                string custID = rd.GetInt32("customerID").ToString();
                radTextBox5.Text = custID;
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablereader.getint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `GetInt32(int index)` takes zero-based column ordinal

so change you code from `string query = "select * from RoadRunnerDB.custo.....` to

```
string query = "select customerID from RoadRunnerDB.customerList....
```

and use `GetString( int index)` as [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablereader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) stated :

```
string custID = rd.GetString(0);
```

Comment: yes!! it kind of worked. I am getting the customerName but not the ID or customerID. Going to try couple of things and report back.

Comment: I also changed my query to

`string.Format("select customerCompanyName, customerID from customerList where customerCompanyName = '{0}'", radMultiColumnComboBox1.Text);`

Comment: `int custID = rd.GetInt32(1);
string custID2 = custID.ToString();
radTextBox5.Text = custID2;` Now it is working Thank you sir.